# Full Mesh Creation from User Inputs in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, mesh

I am working on creating a [full mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aNetworkTopology-FullyConnected.png) as per user inputs with weights, other parameters associated to each edge. As of now, I have a naive implementation of it.

```
import sys
weit = input("Enter Number of Weights: ")
int(weit)
for i in range(0,weit):
    print "Enter details for weit ",i+1
    source=int(input("Enter source:"))
    destination=int(input("Enter Destination:"))
    weight=int(input("Enter Weight:"))
    param=int(input("Enter Param:"))
```

With the graph data I have collected, I will design a bin packing algorithm. Is there a better way to create the Full Mesh as per user inputs in Python?

EDIT 1:

```
import sys
import networkx as nx
i_nodes=input("Enter number of nodes")
print "Graph Creation"
G=nx.complete_graph(i_nodes)
```

Any idea, about how to add user input weights and other parameter values to each bidirectional edge to a complete graph in Networkx?

Comment: deleting the networking tag as it sems completely irrelevant to the question

Comment: It might be not what you want but take a look at [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html), namely `nx.complete_graph()`.

Comment: You're probably using Python3; but if you are using Python2, then you should avoid the input function and use raw_input instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian In NetworkX, I found that I can add weights to the graph, but how can I add multiple parameters concerning to an edge that are entered by an user?

Comment: @thinkcool: NetworkX allows you to use any objects (with some restrictions) as nodes, [edges](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edge.html#networkx.DiGraph.add_edge). Though some helper functions require a certain format.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Can you please see EDIT 1 in the question..

Comment: @thinkcool: `G.add_edge(0,1, param="param1")` adds `{'param': 'param1'}` data to `(0,1)` edge.